# Using flask and react, getting 404 errors when referencing js files in html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, flask

I am attempting to learn the basics flask and react, and have become fairly comfortable with the main ideas of both. Now I am trying to stitch the two together with a python backend served by a flask app and a frontend written with react.

I have successfully followed this tutorial http://aviadas.com/blog/2015/08/05/evaluating-react-dot-js-and-flask/ which seems to be the simplest introduction possible. Now I am attempting to reorganize the author's code by separating my html and react.js code to make it easier to begin expanding the capabilities of the simple app. Should be super straight forward.

My directory structure looks like:

```
├── README.md
├── app.py
├── requirements.txt
└── templates
    └── index.html
    └── script.js
```

app.py contains this code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")

def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

index.html contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Flask React Tutorial</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.2/react.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.2/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mount-point"></div>
        <script type="module" src = "script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and script.js contains:

```
     /*** @jsx React.DOM */
    var FirstComponent = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return (<p1>Hello world.</p1>);
        }
    });
    React.render(<FirstComponent />, document.getElementById('mount-point') );
```

All I did to the original tutorial code was move the js code to the file script.js and replaced the line

```
  <script type="text/jsx">
```

with

```
  <script type="module" src = "script.js"></script>
```

The problem is that when I run the app I get

```
"GET /script.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

I get the same thing if I use the absolute path to my script.js file. There must be some other, probably simple, thing I need to do elsewhere in the code. 
Please note that I am very new to most of this, so as thorough of an explanation as possible would be awesome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to use React and Flask you should setup 2 projects. Flask will be the API and React will be the frontend. This though is an issue with accessing "static files". http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/static/

Comment: Awesome thanks, this seems to point me in two right directions. I am still a little confused about he difference between what I'm doing and what you suggested.

Comment: Here is what I am coming to understand after your comment. Flask will be the API, meaning it stores data, assigns it to urls, and handles requests sent to those urls, but does none of the rendering. React does all the rendering, and knows what to render based on responses from requests sent to the API. Correct me if I'm wrong. So, urls are 'ports' on the the server, correct? React renders to urls as well. Are these different urls than those in the API? Still confused about the level of separation between projects. Excuse my ignorance.

Comment: So what you would do in dev is run 2 servers. You would run the react server on say port 3000 and the flask server on port 8000. The react server would handle everything the user sees and interacts with well the flask server handles things like sending emails, talking to the database, saving files, etc..

Comment: It is normal for this in production to be something like this `www.mydomain.com/*` < react app and one of 2 popular urls for flask `www.mydomain.com/api/*` or `api.mydomain.com/*`. The flask app would take in JSON and give back JSON.

Comment: Then in production you would use something like Nginx/Apache, NodeJS, uwsgi/gunicorn to remove the extra ports from the URL's.